# Loading external HTML files synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

We have a locally run HTML app, generated from a CMS, for a 3rd party system running in a native IOS app.

Each main page needs to be an individual, standalone HTML file.

Shared resources (common html partials, js css etc) used across all pages are in a shared folder.

Loading the CSS and JS is fine, but we need a way to load the shared HTML in BEFORE the first render of the page, as though it were part of the page (else you see the page without the shared content for a split second / a white flash).

We have come up with a few approaches, none of them are very nice, so any thoughts ?

**1) `document.write`**

We wrap each shared html partial in JS:

`document.write('<div class=\'title\'>The Title</div>');`

Then in the main HTML page, we include it with a JS tag..

`<script src="../shared/template.html"></script>`

This works, but uses `document.write` which gets lots of warnings in the console, and we will have to do some processing of the .html files to escape them and wrap them in JS.

**2) Synchronous Ajax - (Sjax?)**

Load the file with `XMLHttpRequest` BEFORE the closing `body` tag, but with the `sync` flag set to false, and then onload insert it into a placeholder node in the main page.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('template-container')[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  });
  xhr.open('GET', '../shared/template.html', false);
  xhr.send();
```

This is much better as we don't have to touch the .html pages at all, and there is no document.write going on.

However, Sync on the main thread is supposedly deprecated  - however, when/if IOS ever remove this I don't know.

**3) `iframe`**

Include the partials as an iframe.

`<iframe src="../shared/template.html"></iframe>`

Issue with this is that we again have to modify the partials so they include the relevant CSS to render, we need to modify the parent file/css to render the iFrame correctly, and has more roundtrips to achieve the same idea as point 1.

**4) `Ajax` / `fetch`**
Both are async, so will always have a slight delay between main render and then loading the external html.

Currently I'm thinking 2, as its the cleanest implementation, but worried if it will really be deprecated.

Any other approaches?

Comment: Forcing the page to wait on the fetch of the html will require synchronous ajax request, and most browsers are deprecating synchronous ajax requests.  You need to reconsider your requirements.